# AngularJS Check Data from MySQL with ID

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have a problem with AngularJS / Routing.
I want to , check data from mysql with post id. 
I have 2 pages :  posts.html and read.html.

posts.html :

```
<div class = 'posts'>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts"><a href="">{{post.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Read.html

```
<div class = 'readpage'>
   //I dont have any idea how can i write this page.
</div>
```

App.js :

```
var App = angular.module("angularApp",["ui.router"]);


App.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider
.state('posts',{
    url : '/posts',
    templateUrl : 'views/posts.html'
})
.state('read',{
    url : 'post/:postid',
    templateUrl : 'views/read.html'
})

  });

 App.controller("mainController",function($scope,$http){

     $http.post('db.php').then(function(response){
          $scope.posts = response.data;
     });
  });
```

dp.php

```
  <?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","lenovo123","angular");
  $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM posts");
  $data_array = array();
  while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   $data_array[]  = $fetch;
 }

  print json_encode($data_array);

 ?>
```

Columns : id , title , body , author.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your need ? You want to click on the link on the page "post" and display the result in the page "read" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you want to load a list of posts in your posts.html (posts state) and after one of those posts is clicked you want to redirect to read.html (reads state). You could do the following:

```
var App = angular.module("angularApp",["ui.router"]);

App.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider
.state('posts',{
    url : '/posts',
    templateUrl : 'views/posts.html',
    controller: 'mainController as vm'
    resolve: {
      posts: ['$http','$q',function($http, $q){
      //This call should be transfered to a service (create a new factory that will handle all of your communication to backend services)
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          $http.post('db.php').then(function(response){
               deferred.resolve(response.data);
           }).catch(function(err){
               deferred.reject();
           });

           return deferred.promise;
      }]
    }
})
.state('read',{
    url : 'post/:postid',
    templateUrl : 'views/read.html',
    controller: 'postController as vm',
    resolve: {
      post: ['http','$q','$stateParams', function($http, $q, $stateParams){
      //Make a new call that will get your post by the post id provided in the state params ( **this is the post selected on posts state** ) - replace the test.php with a proper query that will get you the wanted post

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      //Something like the following:
      $http.post('test.php', $stateParams.postid).then(function(response){
           deferred.resolve(response.data);
       }).catch(function(err){
           deferred.reject();
       });

       return deferred.promise;
      }]
    }
})

  });
```

And then in mainController ( I would name this controller postsController) you just inject the posts that you have previously acquired on state resolve

```
 App.controller("mainController",function($scope,$http, posts){
    var vm = this;
    vm.posts = posts;
  });
```

And in your posts.html view:

```
 <div class = 'posts'>
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in vm.posts"><a ui-sref="read({postid: post.id})">{{post.title}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

With this approach you can remove the following line to avoid double initialization if you have it in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController"></div>
```

Then you can create a new controller that will be executed on read state:

```
 App.controller("postController",function($scope,$http, post){
    var vm = this;
    vm.post = post;
  });
```

And in your read.html view:

```
<div class = 'readpage'>
   <div>{{vm.post.id}}</div>
   <div>{{vm.post.title}}</div>
   <div>{{vm.post.body}}</div>
   <div>{{vm.post.author}}</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

If you are not familiar with the "controllerAs" syntax please check out the following: [Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Comment: Thanks for answer , it worked. But i new at AngularJS. And didn't understand some parts of app.js. Don't have it's easier version ? For example  , can we do this with $state.go() ? :)

Comment: Sure you can. If you want to use that approach then you just need to replace ui-sref="read({postid: post.id})" with: ng-click="vm.changeState(post.id)".

And in your mainController add a new method:
        vm.changeState = function (postId) {
            $state.go('read', { postid: postId });
        };

Or if you dont't want to use controllerAs syntax just do it like this:
 ng-click="changeState(post.id)"

And in your mainController add a new method:
        $scope.changeState = function (postId) {
            $state.go('read', { postid: postId });
        };

Comment: Hello there everyone..I've tried this solution so far its working fine, am getting the posts with links which have ids on them. But the problem am facing is  I cant make them to direct me to read.html. I've opened question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354471/click-post-link-to-display-full-results-on-another-page). Please help